# How to handle paths for a .py file that is imported from different directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project structure as follows:

```
- src/
    - script.py
    - data/
        - tools.py
        - datastuff.py
- data/
    - raw/
```

Both `script.py` and `datastuff.py` can be run on their own, and they both import `tools.py`. Inside of `tools.py`, files from elsewhere in my project are read. For example:

```
raw_data_path = path.join(os.getcwd(), "../..", "data", "raw")
```

This works when I'm running `datastuff.py`, but not if I'm running `script.py`. What's the right way to refer to the `data/raw/` in `tools.py` so that it works in all cases?

Comment: do you have an `if __name__ == '__main__` guard in your executable .py files? If so, you can just specify the relative path in each of `script.py` and `datastuff.py` independently.

Comment: And then pass those relative paths to the functions in `tools.py`? I was hoping to handle all the path stuff in `tools.py`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking is how you deal with the issue that your path relations are different based on where you are making your calls. In that case, an approach is to find your project Parent directory, then base all your file calls off of that location instead.

**Given the following project structure**

```
├── data
│   └── raw
└── src
    ├── data
    │   ├── datastuff.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    └── script.py
```

**Make certain that your src folder has an __init__.py file. Then place the following code in it;**

```
> from pathlib import Path
> 
> def get_project_root() -> Path:
>     """Returns project root folder."""
>     return Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

**Then, within any file, you can access your top level folder with;**

```
from src import get_project_root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = get_project_root()
    print(root)
```

**And you can use that knowledge to load files from any directory doing the following;**

```
from src import get_project_root
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = get_project_root()
    path_to_raw = os.path.join(root, r"data/raw", "file.txt")
    print(path_to_raw)
```

Comment: So then 'path_to_raw' will have to be passed from the executables to the functions in  'tools.py'?

Comment: Also, I'm having trouble importing `src` from files in the `src/data/` directory. Using `from src import get_project_root`I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'`.